# Time Limit Exceeded [c++] : last digit of each of numbers' factorial

Tags: c++

I have a Time Limit Exceeded error in my c++ code.
It's a simple algorithm that output the last digit of each of numbers' factorial given by the user.

Example1 :

Input : 4, output : 4, explanation : 4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1. =  24.  Last digit of 24 is 4.

Example2 :

Input : 5, Output : 0, Explanation : 5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1. =  120.  Last digit of 120 is 0.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Fact(int n){
    int p=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        p = p * i;
    }
    return p;
}

int LastDigit(int n){
    return n % 10;
}


int main()
{
    int t,n;
    cin >> t;
    int T[t];
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        cin >> n;
        T[i]=LastDigit(Fact(n));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        cout <<T[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout << Fact(10);

}
```

Thank you for giving me a detailed answer.

Comment: **Protip:** Variable length arrays aren't a part of C++ standard.

Comment: It'll be better to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your code (i.e. input/output) and your expectations.

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to fix other than lowering your time? Do you know of any specific issue that is causing the higher execution time?

Comment: Most of these contests the obvious solution is too slow. Do you really need to calculate the whole factorial to work out the last digit?

Comment: Regarding @AlanBirtles's comment, I believe this question on another site may help you with reworking your algorithm: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-last-n-digits-of-a-factorial-without-calculating-the-whole-factorial

Comment: The last digit of anything beyond 5! Is always zero...

Comment: @MikeVine In that case the whole program may just as well be a switch statement with 6 cases and the hardcoded answer for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int FactLastDigit(int n) 
{
    if (n > 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        long int number = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            number *= i;
        }
        return number % 10;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int t;

    std::cin >> t;

    std::vector<int> T(t);
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        T[i] = FactLastDigit(n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        std::cout << T[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```